# Access files in shared Google Drive folder without authentication, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, drive

Is there any way to access the direct download links of all files in a publicly shared folder on Google Drive with js and without authentication? No users will have direct access to the client computer so no user authentication is possible.

For example, I've got a folder id or whatever it's called. That folder is shared and not private. I use the id in javascript to call the api and gets an object with all the files (which are, even them, shared), somewhere in that object along with the metadata there's a direct download link.

I don't want you to code for me. I'm just asking for references.

Comment: With JavaScript, are you running a server (with node.js) or a local webpage that is host on localhost or file:// or Google App Script? You have to be more clear on what you meant.

Comment: Sorry, I'd much prefer a solution that works locally.

Comment: Unfortunately every call to the API requires authorization with OAuth2.

Comment: Ok, I need this feature. Do you know if it's doable with any other cloud service? Like Dropbox?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to host files?

Comment: I want to use it to simplify the digital signage system on my previous school.

Comment: If you are running it locally, have you considered creating a local server to grab files on your file system?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100509/discussion-between-9focuspoints-and-derek-).

Answer (score 0):

First Create project in Google Cloud Platform and enable Google Drive API.
From there you will get your API Key.

Node JS Code:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth: Your-API-Key })
let fconf = {};
fconf.maxResults = 10;
fconf.orderBy = "createdTime";
fconf.q = `'${folderId}' in parents`;
drive.files.list(fconf, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    } else {
        response.data.files.map(file => {
            let fileUrl = 'https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=' + file.id
               console.log('fileUrl ', fileUrl )
        })
    }
});
```